# Python: Convert PDF to DOC

Tags: python, bash, pdf, docx, doc

How to convert a pdf file to docx. Is there a way of doing this using python?

I've saw some pages that allow user to upload `PDF` and returns a `DOC` file, like [PdfToWord](http://www.pdftoword.com)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you don't understand my question, I'll edit it

Comment: If the pdf data is tabular, you can use tabula library to process your data and output in doc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have LibreOffice installed

```
lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc '/your/file.pdf'
```

If you want to use Python for this:

```
import os
import subprocess

for top, dirs, files in os.walk('/my/pdf/folder'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            abspath = os.path.join(top, filename)
            subprocess.call('lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc "{}"'
                            .format(abspath), shell=True)
```

Comment: When I execute this command on my terminal, it just open a new _empty_ LibreOffice. I'm doing `lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc 'mypdf.pdf'`. But this seems to be what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Liarez You can specify the output folder in the arguments. By default the converted file may be present in the ~/Home Directory. Check the help options (`lowriter --help`). Sorry, I couldn't test it now.

Comment: Solved! I finally could make the command works! It works as expected, thanks you very much!!

Comment: @alvaroav plz share your command  which is converting  pdf to word using  libreoffice. I have latest version  of libreoffice

Comment: For the macOS users: `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --invisible --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" file-to-convert.pdf`

Answer (score 9):

This is difficult because PDFs are presentation oriented and word documents are content oriented. I have tested both and can recommend the following projects.

1. [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2)
2. [PDFMiner](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer)

However, you are most definitely going to lose presentational aspects in the conversion.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert PDF -> MS Word type file like docx, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327434/is-there-any-way-to-convert-pdf-file-to-docx-using-python).

> [Ahsin Shabbir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3020394/ahsin-shabbir) wrote:

```
import glob
import win32com.client
import os

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 0

pdfs_path = "" # folder where the .pdf files are stored
for i, doc in enumerate(glob.iglob(pdfs_path+"*.pdf")):
    print(doc)
    filename = doc.split('\\')[-1]
    in_file = os.path.abspath(doc)
    print(in_file)
    wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    out_file = os.path.abspath(reqs_path +filename[0:-4]+ ".docx".format(i))
    print("outfile\n",out_file)
    wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16) # file format for docx
    print("success...")
    wb.Close()

word.Quit()
```

This worked like a charm for me, converted 500 pages PDF with formatting and images.

Comment: I think setting `word.visible = 1` is much better option. This will allow the user to see all the messages or warnings shown by word. If we set `word.visible = 0`, word can not show any error/warnings thereby complicating the debugging experience.

Comment: @eleks007-san, reqs_path is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud SDK for python](https://blog.groupdocs.cloud/2019/11/06/convert-pdf-to-editable-word-document-with-python-sdk/) without installing any third-party tool or software.

Sample Python code:

```
# Import module
import groupdocs_conversion_cloud

# Get your app_sid and app_key at https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud (free registration is required).
app_sid = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
app_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create instance of the API
convert_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertApi.from_keys(app_sid, app_key)
file_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.FileApi.from_keys(app_sid, app_key)

try:

        #upload soruce file to storage
        filename = 'Sample.pdf'
        remote_name = 'Sample.pdf'
        output_name= 'sample.docx'
        strformat='docx'

        request_upload = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.UploadFileRequest(remote_name,filename)
        response_upload = file_api.upload_file(request_upload)
        #Convert PDF to Word document
        settings = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertSettings()
        settings.file_path =remote_name
        settings.format = strformat
        settings.output_path = output_name

        loadOptions = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.PdfLoadOptions()
        loadOptions.hide_pdf_annotations = True
        loadOptions.remove_embedded_files = False
        loadOptions.flatten_all_fields = True

        settings.load_options = loadOptions

        convertOptions = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.DocxConvertOptions()
        convertOptions.from_page = 1
        convertOptions.pages_count = 1

        settings.convert_options = convertOptions
 .               
        request = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertDocumentRequest(settings)
        response = convert_api.convert_document(request)

        print("Document converted successfully: " + str(response))
except groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling get_supported_conversion_types: {0}".format(e.message))
```

I'm developer evangelist at aspose.

Comment: Good idea let's send potentially confidential documents to a third party /s

Comment: Customer has complete control of his cloud storage and can use [any cloud storage](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/total/configure-3rd-party/) like Amazon S3/Google Drive/ Azure storage/ Dropbox/ FTP Storage etc. of his choice

Answer (score 1):

Based on previews answers this was the solution that worked best for me using **Python 3.7.1**

```
import win32com.client
import os

# INPUT/OUTPUT PATH
pdf_path = r"""C:\path2pdf.pdf"""
output_path = r"""C:\output_folder"""

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 0  # CHANGE TO 1 IF YOU WANT TO SEE WORD APPLICATION RUNNING AND ALL MESSAGES OR WARNINGS SHOWN BY WORD

# GET FILE NAME AND NORMALIZED PATH
filename = pdf_path.split('\\')[-1]
in_file = os.path.abspath(pdf_path)

# CONVERT PDF TO DOCX AND SAVE IT ON THE OUTPUT PATH WITH THE SAME INPUT FILE NAME
wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
out_file = os.path.abspath(output_path + '\\' + filename[0:-4] + ".docx")
wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16)
wb.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

## With Adobe on your machine

If you have adobe acrobate on your machine you can use the following function that enables you to save the PDF file as docx file

```
# Open PDF file, use Acrobat Exchange to save file as .docx file.

import win32com.client, win32com.client.makepy, os, winerror, errno, re
from win32com.client.dynamic import ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT

def PDF_to_Word(input_file, output_file):
    
    ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)
    src = os.path.abspath(input_file)
    
    # Lunch adobe
    win32com.client.makepy.GenerateFromTypeLibSpec('Acrobat')
    adobe = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.App')
    avDoc = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.AVDoc')
    # Open file
    avDoc.Open(src, src)
    pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    jObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()
    # Save as word document
    jObject.SaveAs(output_file, "com.adobe.acrobat.docx")
    avDoc.Close(-1)
```

Be mindful that the input_file and the output_file need to be as follow:

1. D:\OneDrive...\file.pdf
2. D:\OneDrive...\dafad.docx

Comment: does this preserve all formatting and would it work on linux?

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users with LibreOffice installed try

```
soffice --invisible --convert-to doc file_name.pdf
```

If you get an error like `Error: no export filter found, abording` try this

```
soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to doc file_name.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words for Python supports conversion from PDF to DOCX. The code is pretty simple:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("C:\\Temp\\in.pdf")
doc .save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx")
```

[Aspose.Words support a lot of document formats](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/supported-document-formats/), but at first it has been designed to work with MS Word documents.