# Convert pdf to docx using Libre Office,an error occurs

Tags: python, pdf, docx, libreoffice

I try to convert pdf to docx with Libreoffice,and I use this method provided at [Convert PDF to DOC (Python/Bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358281/convert-pdf-to-doc-python-bash)
,the code is as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess

for top, dirs, files in os.walk('/my/pdf/folder'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            abspath = os.path.join(top, filename)
            subprocess.call('lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc "{}"'
                            .format(abspath), shell=True)
```

However, when I debug it, I get an error:

```
Error: source file could not be loaded
Error: no export filter for C:\Users\owner\desktop\docx\my.docx found, aborting.
Error: no export filter
```

I've searched this using Google a while,however there is no any answer fit to my question.So I'm here  asking for help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code says `--convert-to doc` but you are converting to docx?  It looks like you did not post the actual code used.  Also, does the problem occur when you run a single lowriter command from the command line?  Post the single command as well.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I've tried `--convert-to doc` and '--convert-to docx' ,I must have posted the code for 'doc' and the error message for 'docx'.My mistake!And I can make sure it is not this problem.And as you suggested,I've tried to run the 'lowriter' command in the command line.the same error occurs!

Answer (score 0):

Give export filter for pdf to search file in your directory...

for example:

subprocess.call('lowriter --invisible --convert-to **doc:writer_pdf_export** "{}"'
.format(abspath), shell=True)

or

subprocess.call('lowriter --invisible --convert-to **doc:draw_pdf_export** "{}"'
.format(abspath), shell=True)