# Convert PDF to .docx with Python

Tags: python, pdf, docx, libreoffice, doc

I'm trying to find a way to convert a PDF file to a .docx file with Python.

I have seen other posts related with this, but none of them seem to work correctly in my case.

I'm using specifically

```
import os
import subprocess

for top, dirs, files in os.walk('/my/pdf/folder'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            abspath = os.path.join(top, filename)
            subprocess.call('lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc "{}"'
                            .format(abspath), shell=True)
```

This gives me Output[1], but then, I can't find any .docx document in my folder.

I have LibreOffice 5.3 installed.

Any clues about it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc "/my/pdf/folder/filename.pdf"` in a terminal window.

Comment: @Goyo thanks. But I'm not able to run this commando in the terminal. It doesn't recognize lowriter as an executable command. Why is that?

Comment: How could I know? It is probably related to the way you installed libreoffice. But you'd better figure it out, you can't expect python to run a program when you are unable to run it yourself.

Comment: What is your operating system?  Use [my answer from two weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49763069/5100564) but modify the paths.

Comment: @JimK Thank you very much. I saw your post recently, and I used it as a help for my trouble, and it worked perfectly for converting the pdf to odg. (I checked your answer for that reason). However, I was looking for the conversion to .docx, that seems to be more difficult...
In any case, my operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: @Also - did you find a result for this thread? I am trying to do the same - convert pdf to docx and .txt.

Comment: Can somebody help me on this. ? i need to convert the same ie, from pdf to docx and it should have more accuracy level..

Answer (score 8):

I use this for multiple files

```
####
from pdf2docx import Converter
import os

# # # dir_path for input reading and output files & a for loop # # #

path_input = '/pdftodocx/input/'
path_output = '/pdftodocx/output/'

for file in os.listdir(path_input):
    cv = Converter(path_input+file)
    cv.convert(path_output+file+'.docx', start=0, end=None)
    cv.close()
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a way to convert a `pdf` file into a `Word` file using libreoffice.
However, you can convert from a `pdf` to a `html` and then convert the `html` to a `docx`.
Firstly, get the commands running on the command line. (The following is on Linux. So you may have to fill in path names to the soffice binary and use a full path for the input file on your OS)

```
soffice --convert-to html ./my_pdf_file.pdf
```

then

```
soffice --convert-to docx:'MS Word 2007 XML' ./my_pdf_file.html
```

You should end up with:

my_pdf_file.pdf
my_pdf_file.html
my_pdf_file.docx

Now wrap the commands in your `subprocess` code

Answer (score 4):

Below code worked for me.

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 1
pdfdoc = 'NewDoc.pdf'
todocx = 'NewDoc.docx'
wb1 = word.Documents.Open(pdfdoc)
wb1.SaveAs(todocx, FileFormat=16)  # file format for docx
wb1.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach does not follow the same methodology of using subsystems. However this one does the job of reading through all the pages of a PDF document and moving them to a docx file. Note: It only works with text; images and other objects are usually ignored.

```
#Description: This python script will allow you to fetch text information from a pdf file

#import libraries

import PyPDF2
import os
import docx

mydoc = docx.Document() # document type
pdfFileObj = open('pdf/filename.pdf', 'rb') # pdffile loction
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) # define pdf reader object

# Loop through all the pages

for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
        pdfContent = pageObj.extractText()  #extracts the content from the page. 
        print(pdfContent) # print statement to test output in the terminal. codeline optional.
        mydoc.add_paragraph(pdfContent) # this adds the content to the word document
        
mydoc.save("pdf/filename.docx") # Give a name to your output file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done this with pdf2docx :

```
from pdf2docx import parse
pdf_file = "test.pdf"
word_file = "test.docx"
parse(pdf_file, word_file, start=0, end=None)
```

Comment: It says that it's impossible to opend the file

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install spire.pdf
pip install plum-dispatch==1.7.4

from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *

pdf = PdfDocument()
pdf.LoadFromFile("input.pdf")

pdf.SaveToFile("PdfToDocx.docx", FileFormat.DOCX)
pdf.Close()
```

Comment: While this code my answer the question, your answer would benefit from having some explanation to what the code does to help future readers understand it