# Is there any way to convert Pdf file to Docx using python

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a way in python (tool or function etc.) to convert my pdf file to doc or docx?

I am aware of online converters but I need this in Python code.

Comment: [This Link Is useful for You for convert your file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965818/convert-pdf-to-docx-with-python)

Comment: Thanks . I have tried that link but it's not  satisfying my requirements .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have pdf with lot of pages..below code will work:

```
import PyPDF2

    path="C:\\ .... "
    text=""
    pdf_file = open(path, 'rb')
    text =""
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    c = read_pdf.numPages
    for i in range(c):
         page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
         text+=(page.extractText())
```

Comment: Yes it will..I have done extensive study on this.,..there is no way u can get as it is conversion in Python. The next best solution is online tools which u are not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have MS Word, there is a really simple way to do this using COM. 
Here is a script I wrote that can convert pdf to docx by calling the Word application.

```
import glob
import win32com.client
import os

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 0

pdfs_path = "" # folder where the .pdf files are stored
for i, doc in enumerate(glob.iglob(pdfs_path+"*.pdf")):
    print(doc)
    filename = doc.split('\\')[-1]
    in_file = os.path.abspath(doc)
    print(in_file)
    wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    out_file = os.path.abspath(reqs_path +filename[0:-4]+ ".docx".format(i))
    print("outfile\n",out_file)
    wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16) # file format for docx
    print("success...")
    wb.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Comment: @Ahsin-san, reqs_path is undefined.