# How to convert pdf to docx using python while maintaining the layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, docx

I need help in converting pdf to docx. I found one library pdf2docx but this is a GNU license so I can't use this library to convert is there any library that I can use? I want to maintain the layout and all information and pdf files also contain images.

I have also tried converting the pdf to docx using subprocess this works but the file is corrupted.

Libraries that I have found are:

1. pikepdf
2. pdfminer.six
3. pymupdf
4. pdfrw
5. pdfplumber
   etc...

In short I am looking for a pdf2docx library alternative.
Please help me with this....

Comment: is this solved your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327434/is-there-any-way-to-convert-pdf-file-to-docx-using-python

Comment: Thanks, Ramesh for your solution. but this does not solve my problem. I also need to maintain the pdf layout. The solution in this is not useful I have already tried all this.

Comment: Read this https://splunktool.com/is-there-any-way-to-convert-pdf-file-to-docx-using-python