# Programmatically click the ok button in ms-word

Tags: python, ms-word, com, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to automatically convert pdf files to docx files in python, using (copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255120/12890458)):

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 1
pdfdoc = 'NewDoc.pdf'
todocx = 'NewDoc.docx'
wb1 = word.Documents.Open(pdfdoc)
wb1.SaveAs(todocx, FileFormat=16)  # file format for docx
wb1.Close()
word.Quit()
```

This opens Word and the following prompt appears:

[image]

I want to run my script without user intervention, so is it possible to programmatically click the OK button?

Comment: have you tried selecting "don't show this message again"? then checking if the next times you run the code the window appears? Otherwise the OK button seems focused by default, just emulating a Enter key press should work.

Comment: @Elerium115 I tried "don't show this message again" and it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Open` method has optional parameters that can be specified to avoid the dialog:

```
wb1 = word.Documents.Open(pdfdoc, false)
```

The `ConfirmConversions` parameter is set to `true` to display the `Convert File` dialog box if the file isn't in Microsoft Word format, otherwise just set it to false.