# Extracting bold text from Resumes( .Docx,.Doc,PDF) using Python

Tags: python, text-extraction

I have thousands of resumes in any format like word with .doc, .docx and pdf.

I want to extract bold text from these documents using textract library in python. is there a way to extract using textract?

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: I am currently using textract to extract any document type like PDF or word .  Is it possible to extract lines which are bold?

Comment: have you found any answer?

Answer (score 4):

An easy solution would be to use the *python-docx* package. install the package using ( *!pip install python-docx* )

You'll need to convert your pdf files to .docx . you can do that using any online pdf to docx converter or use [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358281/convert-pdf-to-doc-python-bash) to do that.

the following lines of codes will extract all **bold** and *italic* contents of your resumes and save them in a dictionary called boltalic_Dict. you may retrieve either later on.

```
from docx import *

document = Document('path_to_your_files')
bolds=[]
italics=[]
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if run.italic :
            italics.append(run.text)
        if run.bold :
            bolds.append(run.text)

boltalic_Dict={'bold_phrases':bolds,
              'italic_phrases':italics}
```

Comment: I have files in different formats, .Doc, .Docx, PDF, .RTF. that is why i am using textract library. is it possible to get extract the same information using textract library?

Comment: Revised code in my answer if this code breaks contiguous bold/italic text for others too.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [m.borhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52267853/4938484), since in their code some contiguous bold and italic portions failed to output as single item:

```
from docx import *

document = Document('path_to_your_files')
bolds=[]
italics=[]
last_bold = "" #last bold part
last_italic = "" #last italic part
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if run.italic :
            last_italic = last_italic + run.text
        elif run.bold :
            last_bold = last_bold + run.text
        else:
            italics.append(last_italic)
            bolds.append(last_bold)
            last_italic = ""
            last_bold = ""
italics = [i for i in italics if i]
bolds = [i for i in bolds if i]
boltalic_Dict={'bold_phrases':bolds,
              'italic_phrases':italics}
```