# Use pytesseract to read content that is out of position

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I am using `pytesseract` to read the content related to date/time.
This works well when the content to be read is on the same line.
However, in the following case, I am not even able to use `OpenCV` to identify the area containing information:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxSJi.png)

Can anyone help me find a way to read information like on images? Thanks everyone

Comment: are you trying to read from PDF?

Comment: Right. However, I am not allowed to use the PDF reader tools available on python

Comment: I have also converted the PDF to JPG for reading

Comment: And you are not getting the data in a fixed structured format. right?

Comment: Right. At the moment, I just have a problem with the structure as shown in my image

Comment: have you tried using regex?

Comment: as my description above, I'm trying to use opencv and tesseract to do this

Answer (score 0):

PDF is an unstructured format. You can not get structured data from a PDF. However, to extract information from a PDF you can use some tricks like if your data is italic or bold you can follow [this link](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/52267853/8748098) to extract them. But if your date/time format is not like that you can use `regex` to extract your date/time data. But if you have multiple date/time data and you want to store them for different purposes, you can use Words before and after those date/times to differentiate them. But the point is you can not get the position in PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with my description, I'm trying to use opencv and tesseract.Is there any way to do this?